# Rectangular BackColor of selection in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, controls, richtextbox, backcolor

**Background:**
I'm going to start studying/coding at the local university's library. Since I'm not a student, I won't be able to utilize their wireless internet access. Since StackOverflow is such a great resource, I want to be able to take it with me, so I'm building a small desktop application to load/search/display the most recent data dumps.

**Problem:**
I want to display code blocks in the same sort of rectangular block as this site does, so I played with the RichTextBox control to try to create this effect. Unfortunately, the RichTextBox.SelectedBackColor property only colors the actual text, when what I want is a rectangle reaching to the outer limits of the selection.

**Example:**
This is what I am able to produce with the RichTextBox:
[image]

This is what I would like to create:
[image]

**Questions:**

- Is there any way to produce this effect using the RichTextBox?
- **If not,** are there any other controls I could use to create this effect?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, there is no mention of controlling this behavior on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787605(VS.85).aspx).